# Change button size FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, flowlayout

I'm trying to change button size but when I set width, height automatically changes too even though height has own value. How can I change only width (or height)? I need this to my "reset" and "calc" buttons.
Code (without unnecessary other code)

```
class Wind extends JButton {
//declaration of variables
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
    int s = (int) (d.getWidth() < d.getHeight() ? d.getHeight() : d.getWidth());
    return new Dimension(s, s);
}
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            JComponent gui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

            for (int ii = 1; ii < 20; ii++) {
                final  JButton button = new Wind("");

                gui.add(button);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    }

                });

            }

            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 3, 4, 8));
            final JButton reset = new Wind("Reset");
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(40,80);

            reset.setPreferredSize(dim);

            gui.add(reset);

            reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }

            });

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Name of my frame");
            f.add(gui);

            final JButton cal = new Wind("Calc");

            gui.add(cal);
            cal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    }
            });

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setSize(350, 450);
            f.setResizable(false);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
```

}

Comment: Why is your `JButton` a `new Window`?

Comment: This is out of any context. Post full working/running code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from what I see, you force the width and height of your `Wind` instances to have the same value:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
    int s = (int) (d.getWidth() < d.getHeight() ? d.getHeight() : d.getWidth());
    return new Dimension(s, s);
}
```

`Wind#getPreferredSize` returns a `Dimension` instance that holds both the width and the height that your `Wind` instance wants to have. In your case, it returns a new instance of `Dimension` made of twice the same value: `s`, which is the biggest of the width and height you set via `Wind#setPreferredSize`. You probably want to do as @Elliott Frisch just suggested :)

By the way, you're also doing toward the end:

```
frame.pack()
...
frame.setSize(...);
```

In my opinion, you should do either one or the other, but there is no point in calling both methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of your `getPreferredSize()` method -

```
// sets s to the least of height and width.
int s = (int) (d.getWidth() < d.getHeight() ? d.getHeight() : d.getWidth());
return new Dimension(s, s); // <-- sets height and width the same.
```

I think you want to use (depending on your objective) -

```
if (d.getWidth() < d.getHeight()) {
  return new Dimension(d.getWidth(), d.getHeight());
}
return new Dimension(d.getHeight(), d.getWidth());
```